# automatización de búsquedas en google con selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy realizando un script en python que me permita realizar búsquedas en google y luego entrar en un enlace de resultado y repetir la acción de forma indefinida.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
import os
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

HOME_DIRECTORY = os.environ.get('HOME')

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()

options.add_argument("--width=800");

options.add_argument("--height=640");

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(HOME_DIRECTORY + "/.mozilla/firefox/fao18bjc.default")

options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/firefox"

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile,firefox_options=options)         

print("Navegando a google...")

browser.get('https://www.google.co.ve')

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "hplogo"))
    )
finally:

    archivo = open("search.txt", "r")

    def busqueda(palabra):
        search = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
        search.send_keys(palabra, Keys.ENTER)
        print("Buscando... " + palabra)
        time.sleep(20)
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "logo"))
            )
        finally:
            links = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='g']//h3/a")
            for link in links:
                print(link.get_attribute("href"))
            link = random.choice(links)
            print("Navegando a " + link.get_attribute("href"))
            link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[starts-with(@href,'"+ link.get_attribute('href') + "')]")
            link.click()
            time.sleep(20)      
            print("Navegando a google...")
            browser.get('https://www.google.co.ve')     

    for palabra in archivo.readlines():     
        busqueda(palabra)

    browser.close()
```

En el primer segmento de código hago la importación de funciones y cofiguración de selenium. La parte principal es luego del primer try: | finally:

El código se ejecuta perfectamente en la primera búsqueda:

1 - Navega a google

2 - Rellena el input text del buscador con una palabra obtenida de un archivo de texto

3 - Crea un arreglo con todos los enlaces que arroja el resultado de la búsqueda y lo almacena en la variable "links"

4 - Selecciona un enlace de forma aleatoria con la función random.

5 - Hace click en el enlace seleccionado

6 - Vuelve a google para repetir el proceso. Cuando hace una nueva búsqueda en arreglo con enlaces dice estar vacio y el código se detiene mostrando el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 69, in <module>
    busqueda(palabra)
  File "test.py", line 54, in busqueda
    link = random.choice(links)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 277, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Alguien tiene idea de lo que podría estar pasando ? al principio creía que era por que  todavía la página no se había cargado por completo y por ende no encontraba los enlaces, pero con la función "time" le fui añadiendo tiempo de espera y nada.

Comment: búsquedas muy rápidas o automatizadas te van a presentar un captcha, como alternativa podes usar el api que te da [100 búsquedas gratis por día 020/11](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Answer (score 0):

Observando unos cuantos ejemplos de búsquedas parece como si el problema estuviera  en tu ruta XPATH, los enlaces que están dentro de un `h3` son los sombreados en rojo en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los resultados 'normales' listados (en verde) tienen la estructura:

```
<div class="g">
    <div data-hveid=...>
        <div class="rc">
            <div class="r"><a href="link_que_buscamos"
```

Esto hace que en búsquedas dónde solo existen los segundos obtengas una lista de enlaces vacía y el consiguiente error de `random` al no tener nada dónde elegir.

Una solución simple podría ser cambiar el XPATH a algo así:

```
"//div[@class='r']/a[@href]"
```

Un ejemplo simplificado (eliminado los parámetros de configuración personales) de tu código sería:

```
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



def buscar(palabra, driver):
    print("Buscando", palabra)
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.ve/search?q=" + palabra)

    result_xpath = "//div[@class='r']/a[@href]"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, result_xpath)))

    results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, result_xpath)
    links = [result.get_attribute("href") for result in results]

    if links:
        for link in links:
            print(link)

        random_link = random.choice(links)
        print('Navegando a', random_link)
        driver.get(random_link)
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    else:
        print("No se encontraron resultados")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    palabras = ("stackoverflow", "foo", "bar")

    for palabra in palabras:
        buscar(palabra, browser)
```

---

Una última observación, debes evitar usar `readlines` a no ser que requieras una lista con todas las líneas del fichero simultáneamente (para ordenarlas por ejemplo). En caso contrario, por eficiencia usa simplemente un ciclo `for` para iterar sobre el archivo línea a linea tratándolo como un generador.

Por otro lado, ni esta forma de obtener las líneas ni `readlines` eliminan los caracteres de fin de línea `\n`, `\r`, etc. Para eliminarlos puedes usar `str.rstrip()`. Por último, es siempre buena practica cerrar el archivo explícitamente y no dejar la tarea al GC, esto puedes hacerlo con el métododo `close` o mejor, usa `with`:

```
with open("search.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for palabra in archivo:     
        busqueda(palabra.rstrip(), browser)
```

> **Nota:** si Google detecta actividades extrañas o se excede cierto número de búsquedas probablemente te terminará pidiéndote que pases un pequeño test de Turing para asegurarse de tu humanidad, A.K.A captcha :) o incluso llegando a bloquear la ip. Con lo que el script fallará...